# python changing value of column with loc doesnt change nothing

Tags: python, pandas

I have df that I want to change the column 'b' for all rows when column a is equal to 1, to numbers in the range [0.5,1].
for example:

```
a   b
0   0.2
0   0.4
1   0.02
1   0.001
```

desire df:

```
a   b
0   0.2
0   0.4
1   0.7
1   0.8
```

My code is:

```
df[df['a']==1].reset_index(drop=True).loc[0:len(df[df['a']==1]), 'b'] = np.linspace(0.5,0.99,len (df[df['a']==1]))
```

But nothing changed.
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For modify column in original ataFrame use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), for count `True` values use `sum`:

```
m = df['a']==1
df.loc[m, 'b'] = np.linspace(0.5,0.99, m.sum())
print (df)
   a     b
0  0  0.20
1  0  0.40
2  1  0.50
3  1  0.99
```

EDIT: For match first `N` values: (`N` is less like number of `True`s in mask `m`):

```
N = 3
m = (df['a']==1)
m1 = m[m].head(N).reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)
df.loc[m1, 'b'] = np.linspace(0.5,0.99, N)
```

Comment: Thanks. its worked, can you pls tell me why mine doesn't work?

Comment: @nay - because chained indexing. `df[df['a']==1]` return new DataFrame, so if assign  `np.linspace`there original is not changed.